# Clojure example: I cannot comprehend what are the values of "%2" and "%1" in "(str %2 %1)"

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, lisp

I was doing some research about clojure (beginner) and I found an example, the thing is I cannot comprehend what are the values of "%2" and "%1" in "(str %2 %1)". The full example is the following:

```
(defn my-reverse [s]
  (let [lst (list)]
    (reduce #(str %2 %1)
             (mapcat #(conj lst %1) s))))
```

I understand that the %2 refer to a second argument but I only see one argument value after the "#(str %2 %1)" which is the mapcat expression, which should be the %1.

Thanks for your help. Hope I have been clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#(str %2 %1)` is the first argument to [`reduce`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce):

> (reduce f coll)
>
> f should be a function of 2 arguments...returns the result of applying
>   f to the first 2 items in coll, then applying f to that result and the
>   3rd item, etc.

So one argument to `f` is the current value to process (the current item in the collection `coll`) and the other is the accumulated result so far.

In this case the result of `(mapcat #(conj lst %1) s)` is the collection.  In the first call to `#(str %2 %1)` the arguments `%1` and `%2` will be the first two values in that collection.  The next time it will be called with that result and the third value in the collection.  Thus building up a string containing all the values that `(mapcat #(conj lst %1) s)` produced.

Answer (score 3):

The notation `#(...)` is a shorthand for creating an anonymous function.

The longer way to create an anonymous function is a lambda expression, introduced by the symbol `fn` in clojure:

```
(fn [arg1 arg2]
  (do-something-with arg1 arg2))
```

The shorthand lets you omit the `fn` and the argument list, using default argument names instead:

```
#(do-something-with %1 %2)
```

So, your examples expanded:

```
#(str %2 %1)
```

expands to

```
(fn [thing1 thing2]
  (str thing2 thing1))
```

and

```
#(conj lst %1)
```

expands to

```
(fn [thing]
  (conj lst thing))
```